# What statistics should I use to combine multiple rankings?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, ranking

Problem:

I have a list of genes and I am checking certain factors for each gene. I have individual scoring system for each factor for each gene. My final table/matrix looks like this:

```
Gene    Factor1    Factor2    Factor3    Factor4
ALS     0.006      1.0        2.3        0.8
NCLS    0.09       0.8        1.8        0.18
MLB     0.4        0.0        1.8        0.78
BJ      1.1        0.0        0.75       0.18
```

The scores for each factor is independent and comparable to score within that factor only, i.e., `1.1` is very good for `factor1`, but may not be so good for `factor3`. However, for any given factor, higher the number better.

What I am trying to achieve is a ranking of genes. From the example, ALS and MLB should be on the top because for ALS, factor 2-4 have highest values, for MLB, `factor2` is `0` but other factors have high values.

Can you suggest what statistics can be done on matrices like this to create a ranking and level of significance? Can I normalize the score for each factor by calculating Standard Score/z-score (even though all of them don't follow a normal distribution)? What other normalization can be done? Can I instead rank the genes independently for each factor, and then somehow combine the ranks to create a final ranking?

Comment: Great pointer! Will read that! someone also suggested Bayesian hierarchical modeling, have to read that too

Comment: Should be migrated to CV, but I believe you wish to use [Cohen's Kappa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa)

Comment: Can't seem to migrate to CV! Trying to figure out! Will look into Cohen's Kappa! Thanks!

Comment: Cohen's kappa seems for categorical values, while mine is not categorical

Comment: Calcualting weighted arithmetic mean mean will do. Different weights can be assigned to each factor and weighted mean can be used for ranking.